# swift spritekit physics body materializing in a weird place

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to put a physics body to a line.

For some reason the physics body ends up materializing on the lower left corner.

How can I control the position of a physics body? I was under the impression that once I had attached the body into a shape, it would automatically take its shape.

Here's the code:

```
    var distance = calculateDistance(wayPoints[wayPoints.count-1], point2: wayPoints[wayPoints.count-2])

    var linePhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: distance, height: 1.0))
    linePhysicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Line
    linePhysicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
    linePhysicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
    linePhysicsBody.dynamic = false
    linePhysicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    lineNode.removeFromParent()
    lineNode = SKShapeNode()
    lineNode.physicsBody = linePhysicsBody
    lineNode.name = "drawingLine"
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw
    lineNode.lineWidth = 5.0
    lineNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    lineNode.glowWidth = 1.0

    self.addChild(lineNode)
```

[image: physics body]

Comment: the shape is relative to the node's position, and the node's position is what? By default it's 0,0.

Comment: Node should be where the red line is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not positioned your line node. That means per default is't on point(0,0). 
As LearnCocos2D mentioned in his comment. You are drawing then a path relative to your line node position. That does not influence your physicsBody. This is still positioned at (0,0)

Comment: ahh..ok, so the nodes aren't aligned even though I have set the following: lineNode.physicsBody = linePhysicsBody. Thanks!